# Problems with firewall and Google Analytics. What we should do to allow Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Disclaimer: We have read [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/283345/how-can-we-open-our-firewall-to-allow-google-analytics).

We have opened

- ssl.google-analytics.com
- www.google-analytics.com
- google-analytics.com

However we have the following problem:[image: Please note the JSON error]
(see the JSON response)

...also the next line has the following response:

[image: Next error]

**What should we open / on our firewall in order to allow GAnalytics to work?**

Note: We have an antivirus on our workstations. We use the latest Firefox with no extensions involved - we tried also in an incognito window; still the same problem. Also we cleared the browser' cache data.

Comment: This looks more like a permissions problem inside google analytics, than a firewall problem.

Comment: Thanks - Ok - but then why the errors? Also when we try to click on User Management it says "Unable to load data".

Comment: The error message clearly shows `Missing permissions`.

Comment: Yes- forgot to say: I am the administrator and the only one with rights on it There is nobody else. Also I have other accounts shared with others (big companies) and also on these I have the same problem and I know that then didn't change anything.